# Enemy Within headshot bonus damage progression

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

In Enemy Unknown, Headshot used to give bonus damage on crits based on your sniper's gun. In Enemy Within, the bonus damage now rises with the sniper's rank. How much bonus damage does it give for each rank?

Comment: Don't know the answer, but the highest damage I saw with a headshot from a colonel with a plasma sniper rifle was 19, which is massive.

Comment: Do you mean critical hits? Those are not set, but using headshot increases the chance of a hit being critical. in terms of crits, they work the same, except that headshot is needed to crit with squadsight.

Comment: @legacy: No, I mean bonus damage on crits. Unfortunately, I'm not going to have access to the game until next weekend to check the description, so I can't show you the wording, but headshot crits do more damage than regular crits. Here's the description from Enemy Unknown, before the change: "Fire a shot with +30% critical chance and **extra damage on critical hits**, based on the tech level of the sniper rifle. 2 turn cool down."